# Ubuntu installing (recompiling) php modules

Tags: ubuntu, php5, apache-2.2

According to PHP documentation, if you want to add something to php, you need to rerun configure, make and make install. In my case, I see no errors while doing this, but changes are not shown with phpinfo(). The only way to actually change something is to remove php with make distclean and install anew with all the configure options. Any ideas?

Apache is 2.2.
Ubuntu 9.04
PHP 5.3.1

Apache compiled from source and so is PHP.

Comment: Did you stop and restart Apache after recompiling PHP?

Comment: Goes without saying :) Actually I stopped Apache before recompiling php and started it after, just in a case. All the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always had to a make distclean to get the version number/built on date to update, but it's still enabled the feature I've added with just a re-configure.

I've always got into the practice of running make distclean if I change the configure options anyway.